# Creating branch links from iOS that shows the same values as dashboard link

Tags: swift, deep-linking, branch.io

Product team already created a quick link on dashboard, and it already has a Title, Description, and ImageURL. It's something like this https://myapp.app.link/ticket

I am showing tickets on my iOS application. Whenever user selects `share` option on a ticket, I am using below code to populate iOS share sheet

```
let buo = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: "ticket/id?=" + ticketId)
buo.contentMetadata.customMetadata["id"] = ticketId
buo.publiclyIndex = true
buo.locallyIndex = true

let lp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
lp.addControlParam("channel", withValue: "app")
lp.addControlParam("feature", withValue: "ticket_share")
lp.addControlParam("$deeplink_path", withValue: "ticket/?id=" + ticketId)

buo.showShareSheet(with: lp, andShareText: message, from: viewController, completion: nil)
```

When I share this link, it appears something like https://myapp.app.link/RANDOMNUMBERS and I don't see the Title, Description, or ImageURL that are set at branch dashboard.

How can I create a URL using `BranchUniversalObject` and `BranchLinkProperties` that fits the one on dashboard (so something like this https://myapp.app.link/ticket?id=123123) and shows the correct Title, Description, and ImageURL?

**Edit**: When I try to add `lp.alias = "ticket"` I am getting below error from branch sdk

```
Error Domain=io.branch.sdk.error Code=1001 "A resource with this identifier already exists."
```

I don't want to push a new version of the app everytime we want to change shared description or image, that's why I want to use existing created link on branch dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to update your app each time social media tags such as title or image are updated. You can do this per link basis (https://dashboard.branch.io/quick-links/qlc/config/ under `Social Media` tab) or globally on link settings: https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings/general. Alternatively, you can add the following OG tags in the link data when creating links via the SDK or API: $og_title, $og_description, $og_image_url. More info on this: https://docs.branch.io/activity-reports-analytics/content-analytics/#how-does-branch-identify-my-content

Comment: Those configurations have already been made on dashboard for different links. But my problem is I can't see them when I share a `ticket` in my iOS app. I can see the default social media title, desc, image but not ticket link's title, desc, image

Comment: Also, I tried adding `$og_title` and `$og_description` programmatically with the same values as ticket link's social media title and description on dashboard, and I started to get `A resource with this identifier already exists` error from branch server